# rails post path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

I've an issue with the paths in the views and I don't know how to solve it.
I've "categories" that has_many "posts" and "posts" that belongs_to "categories".

1.- I want to show on home page the truncate last post of an specific category (the ID number "1"). Then I want that post to link to the show post path but I get this error:

"Unknow Action
The action 'index' could not be found for PostsController"

I think I've my paths wrong because I don't need the index view because I'm only going to show that specific post. So, I think that category_posts_path(@last_post) is not the right path (I don't know where to look for more info about making the route path in the views...). Actually, the browser is showing me that is looking for the "2" category when it is a post of the "1" category...? What am I doing wrong?
This is the browser route:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/categories/2/posts
```

This is my views/categories/home.html.erb file:

```
<div class="post_details">
 <h2><%= @last_post.title %></h2>
 <%= image_tag @last_post.image(:header), class: "post_image" %>
 <p><%= truncate @last_post.body, length: 100 %></p>
 <p class="button"><%= link_to "READ MORE", category_posts_path(@last_post) %></p>
</div>
```

2.- I have another path problem in the views/categories/show.html.erb file. I have a loop to show all the post of one specific category, but when I link in some post (to show it) there is the "index" error again:

"Unknow action
The action 'index' could not be found for PostsController"

This is the browser route:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/categories/1/posts
```

This is the views/categories/show.html.erb file:

```
<div class="post_details">
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, category_posts_path(post) %></h2>
    <%= image_tag post.image(:header), class: "post_image" %>
    <p><%= post.body %></p>
</div>
```

This is the categories_controller.rb file:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_categories

  def index

  end

  def show

    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

  end

  def home
    if params[:set_locale]
        redirect_to root_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else

      @category = Category.find_by_id(1)

      @last_post = @category.posts.order("created_at desc").first

    end
  end

  def get_categories
    @categories = Category.all.order("rank asc, name asc")    
  end

end
```

This is my posts_controller.rb file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


    def show
        @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
        @post = @category.posts.find(params[:id])
    end


end
```

This is my route.rb file:

```
  scope '(:locale)' do

    resources :categories do
      resources :posts
    end

    resources :contacts

    root 'categories#home'

    get "/contact" => "contacts#new"

    # static pages
    get "/investment" => "contents#investment"
    get "/partner-with-us" => "contents#partner", as: "partner"
    get "/our-companies" => "contents#companies", as: "companies"
    get "/site-map" => "contents#sitemap", as: "sitemap"
    get "/terms-and-conditions" => "contents#terms", as: "terms"
    get "/privacy" => "contents#privacy"

  end
```

Comment: can you post the output of "rake routes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are nesting routes you should always consider what is the parent and whats a child in given route. Since your paths don't know anything about your associations you have to explicitly define every object in the nesting.

I.e. since you nested posts in categories linking to last post in given category would look like this:
`category_post_path(@category, @last_post)`

(I think you have also a typo there - `category_posts_paths` - which links to posts index index - hence the error. Use `category_post_path.` instead, and give it both parent category and the post.

You can run `rake routes` to see exact information on paths (or go to `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` )

Comment: Thanks madsheep, that was the problem, and with your explanation I just figured out how to change the views/categories/show.html.erb file too like this: category_post_path(@category, post)